# Firebase RealtimeDatabase local emulator doesn't work as intended

Tags: typescript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I'm trying do develop some firebase functions;
I'm usign Firebase tools with functions and relatime database emulators.

When I manage to catch an update to a certain field on my db I want to make a query to get a list (of users) in my db.

```
//index.ts

const {onValueUpdated} = require("firebase-functions/v2/database");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");


admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.database();


export const updateLeaderboard = 
  onValueUpdated(
    {
      ref: `/users/{userId}/games/{gamesId}/lastScore`
    },
    (event: any) => {
      const userId = event.params.userId;

      console.log(event.params);
      
      
      db.ref(`/users/${userId}`)
      .once( "value", (result: any) => {
        const user = result.val(); // -> this prints null

        console.log(user);
        
      });

      // I've also tried this and got null as well
      // db.ref(`/users/${userId}`)
      //  .get()
      //  .then((result: any) => {
      //    const user = result.val()
      //    console.log(user);     
      //  });

    }
  );
```

My `db` const seems to be empty: I've started the debugger and I've seen that the query uses the following url:

`http://127.0.0.1:9000/users/my-user-id/`
so I've tried to reach that path via browser with: `127.0.0.1:9000/users.json` to check the database: all I get is `null`;

Firebase config:

```
{
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "database": [
    {
      "instance": "my-instance",
      "rules": "database.rules.json"
    }
  ],
  "emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "database": {
      "enabled": true,
      "port": 9000
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true,
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    }
  }
}
```

database.rules.json:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
    }
}
```

How can I set up properly my local environment?
I've used `firebase init emulators` and enabled `Database` and `Functions`. What should I try now?

Comment: You are mixing up `typescript` with `javascript`. import the libraries as follow: https://codefile.io/f/eo5MchBAVx

Comment: @RoopaM importing libraries as you sugget throws an error

Comment: Can you share the error?